# c++ function overload ambiguous

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, lexical

in c++

```
void foo(int i)
{ std::cout<<"int"<<std::endl; }

void foo(float i)
{ std::cout<<"float"<<std::endl; }

void foo(void *i)
{ std::cout<<"void *"<<std::endl; }

void foo(bool b)
{ std::cout<<"bool"<<std::endl; }

void main() { foo(0); }
```

when compiling this, it makes error.
in visual-studio 2008, the error is **C2668:'function' : ambiguous call to overloaded function**

i know why this problem occur and i know a solution that using-time typecast. but i think this is not a good solution because using this way is kill the lexicality of function overloading.

in my project, i making a lexical-object that change auto type to int,float,std::basic_string and function pointer. overload all typecast operator and creator. but when i input a 'NULL', the error C2668 occurs.

in fact it is almost no problem . the only serious problem is when using FALSE. my project is core library and so i can't guide every end-client programmer.

who knows the trick or tip of solve this problem more smart way?

Comment: This compiles fine on gcc 4.5.

Comment: If this is your real code then report a compiler bug

Answer (score 2):

As it stands right now, your code should not cause an error -- there's no ambiguity. When passing `0` (an `int`), it's clear that `foo(int)` (identity conversion) is a better fit than any of the others (even though 0 can also be implicitly converted to the types for all the other overloads).

My immediate guess would be that the code you're testing isn't quite the same as you've posted. If, for example, you did *not* have the overload taking `int`, I'd expect a error about ambiguous overloads (since, as noted above, there are implicit conversions from `0` to the types taken by all the other overloads). I've confirmed that VC++ 2008 accepts the code as is (and so do VC 2010 and the beta of VC11 and g++ 4.7.0).

As an aside I'd note that `main` should really return an `int` (though it's almost certainly unrelated to the question at hand).

Comment: you are right. to avoid the problem going too much complicated i just simplicated it. i using vs2008 and i overloaded int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long. because the every programmer used STL it returns sometimes **size_t** or other programmer using **DWORD**. so i just only one overload int from int-series now, ignore the compiler warning of typecasting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could define your `FALSE` to `((bool)0)` instead of just 0 (why not use `false` instead?!).

Also, if you think about it, having `f(int *)` and `f(char *)` and calling `f(NULL)` **is** ambiguous, so you need a cast anyway! The compiler doesn't magically know your intentions unless you tell it. So if something is inherently ambiguous, you just have to make it unambiguous by casting.

Comment: In C++, `#define NULL ((void *)0)` is harmful. It means you'd have to add a cast to every use of `NULL`. And overriding something the standard library defined seems like a pretty bad idea in general.

Comment: ok i test that way but i meet same problem. thank you a lot. i just only using 'int' in this ambiguous. void* (function pointer) is make other setter/getter template function. I think the ambiguous problem unavoidabily.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to define any token which is defined by the standard library (even if you didn't include that header)

Answer (score 0):

C++11 corrects this by introducing a new keyword to serve as a distinguished null pointer constant: nullptr. It is of type nullptr_t, which is implicitly convertible and comparable to any pointer type or pointer-to-member type. It is not implicitly convertible or comparable to integral types, except for bool.